# get nextPageToken within my ruby program

Tags: ruby, api, youtube-api

I made this little program in Ruby, it permits to get all my liked videos. But since the maxResult is 50 and i have 1200 videos i need to use the nextPageToken.

But i don't inderstand how to use it in my program.

this is the code :

```
def playlist_items_list_by_playlist_id(service, part, **params)
    params = params.delete_if { |p, v| v == ''}
  response = service.list_playlist_items(part, params)
  print_results(response)

end




playlist_items_list_by_playlist_id(service, 'snippet',
  max_results: 50,
  playlist_id: 'LLkyneo6XAv1no1jH33K2Bmg')
```

I tried to put `:pageToken => next_page_token`beside the the playlist_id line but it is not working.

Can someone help me ?

Thank you

Comment: are you using a particular gem to access this data?

Comment: only the youtube api v3

Comment: so you have written all the methods yourself? in that case we will need to see the method `list_playlist_items` because the API response will include a "nextPageToken" but I have no idea how you are parsing this data. That being said there is already a very full functional library `yt` that will facilitate this for you

Comment: the code and the methods ares inspired by the doc from the api (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list). You are right there is a "nextpagetoken" include, it seems it is a parameter but i am not able put it in my code :/